# Retrieving Auth0 Management APIv2 Token

Tags: auth0

As outlined in the [Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens), I am attempting to retrieve a management api token by making a POST request using jQuery from my Ember App:

```
getToken() {
  let settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://brittshroyer.auth0.com/oauth/token",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{grant_type:client_credentials, 
              client_id: 123, 
              client_secret: fakesecret123, 
              audience: https://brittshroyer.auth0.com/api/v2/}"
  }
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    return console.log('RESPONSE', response);
  });
}
```

As instructed, I have created and initialized a 'Non-Interactive Client' and I have whitelisted 'localhost:4200' (since that is where I am running my Ember App) in the Allowed Origins (CORS) section in the configuration of my client within Auth0. Still, I am running into the following CORS error upon making the POST request: [image]

I'm fairly familiar with CORS, but clearly not familiar enough. Do I need to add a certain header to the payload? Is there a configuration step within Auth0 I am missing? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 400“* seems to be the actual problem. = “Bad request”, which would seem to indicate your server’s deciding there’s something about your request that’s not what it’s expecting

Comment: Britt - are you trying to retrieve a Resource API Access token for your own API?  Or a management API access token to call operations against Auth0 API endpoints?

Comment: Britt - did you see my answer below which fully solves your question? Please can you mark as the correct answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Britt - any update? Did the answer posted assist?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me - please just replace with your **TENANT**, **client_id value**, and **client_secret value**.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>


var settings = {
  async: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  url: "https://{{TENANT}}.auth0.com/oauth/token",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type":"application/json"
  },
  "data": "{\"client_id\":\"Z7HtXBOBPXXXXXXXQcJ3Ma\",\"client_secret\":\"FPWb45XXXXXX96U5XmBUZkUXXXXODDJ88NY\",\"audience\":\"https://brittshroyer.auth0.com/oauth/token\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

In your Client (not API) on the Auth0 Dashboard, remember to add the `Allowed Callback URLs` (which I believe you are already doing). eg.

[image]

Where I think your code went wrong, was somehow it was malformed JSON. In the `data` section of the JSON snippet above, notice how the value is escaped. This is similar to the code snippet Auth0 offer when click the Try button in the APIs section of the Dashboard.

**Note on quick testing:** I had npm module [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) installed, so just named my snippet above `temp.html` and ran `serve` from the same folder. It is then served at `http://localhost:5000/temp.html`. You can see the output by refreshing the page and viewing the console in web browser developer tools.

Let me know if you have any problems, and please mark this answer as correct if it helps you solve your problem! :)